# Can you recommend Performance Analysis tools for PHP?

Tags: php, performance, testing

Can anyone recommend some useful performance analysis tools for PHP scripts? Anything that could help me find problematic or unusually slow blocks of code, details about execution time, etc. would be really helpful. I know there are tools out there, but I'm wondering what people recommend as being the most useful and well-designed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try [webgrind](http://code.google.com/p/webgrind/). It gives you the profiling of CacheGrinder in an easy to read, browser based format. I'm on a Mac and it has made profiling a breeze.

Comment: This looks really cool! I'll definitely be looking into this one.

Answer (score 4):

XDebug's [profiler](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler) is good. But then I'm a KDE user... I think you could install the KCacheGrind in other window managers though.

Comment: Wingrind is still functional for Windows based developers

Comment: MacCallGrind isn't too shabby for Mac folks (outside of virtual machines to run KCacheGrind, which is bottom line the best tool for parsing these callgrind dumps).

Answer (score 1):

Xdebug profiler is pretty good but the CacheGrinder can be a little difficult to interpret.

Zend Platform (expensive if you're not running the developers license) will alert you to issue code and bad use of resources.

Answer (score 1):

I'm personally a fan of [XHProf](http://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof), one of [Facebook's open source initiatives](http://developers.facebook.com/xhprof/). This, along with the XDebug dumps, is crucial in determining performance bottlenecks. Plus, the UI (and particularly, the weighted image-based callgraph functionality) rocks.

I have used this across the Gawker Media network in the past (again, along with XDebug-style dumps), to help focus our performance-geared development efforts.

Answer (score 0):

See SD's [PHP Profiler](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Profilers/PHPProfiler.html).   Measures frequence of execution across your entire application and provides a hotspot graphical display of highly-executed code.  No changes necessary to PHP server to install this.