# Performance concerns on sanitizing all user input using PHP array_map

Tags: php, performance, sanitize

I'm running this function to sanitize all user input through out my site, but it worries me that it may be very performance intensive...

```
 // function for cleaning arrays, recursively for arrays held inside arrays
    function array_clean($array)
    {
        // if its an array, walk each element recursively
        if(is_array($array))
        {
            return array_map("escape", $array);
        }

        // until its a single element, then clean the single element
        else
        {
            return escape($array);
        }
    }

    // Recursively walk our global variables
    $_POST= array_map("array_clean", $_POST);
    $_GET= array_map("array_clean", $_GET);
    $_REQUEST= array_map("array_clean", $_REQUEST);
    $GLOBALS= array_map("array_clean", $GLOBALS);
    $_SERVER= array_map("array_clean", $_SERVER);
    $_FILES= array_map("array_clean", $_FILES);
    $_COOKIE= array_map("array_clean", $_COOKIE);
    $_SESSION= array_map("array_clean", $_SESSION);
    $_ENV=array_map("array_clean", $_ENV);
```

I need your insight.. Thanks

Comment: Unless you have a specific reason to, I would avoid running this on _ENV, _SERVER.  I would also avoid GLOBALS as its huge -- and you shouldn't be accessing user input via GLOBALS anyways (thats what _POST, _GET, _REQUEST and _COOKIES are for).

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry, profile.

Never trust your instinct or anyone's opinion on where performance bottlenecks are, run a profiler and know for sure.

If you need to find a profiler, Xdebug has some pretty [good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133686/what-is-the-best-way-to-profile-php-code) [reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145402/can-you-recommend-peformance-analysis-tools-for-php).

Comment: ok, thanks but do you recommend any one in particular I'm yet to use anyone successfully